# Error messege Strict Standards on joomla site

Tags: php, mysqli, joomla3.0

On the top of my joola website I get this error:

```
Strict Standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference in /home/mysite/public_html/templates/mysite/index.php on line 77
```

When I look up the index.php file that is referred to above and go to line 77 I see:

```
$user =& JFactory::getUser();
```

I think there is something wrong with that code, some how I need to change the:

```
JFactory::getUser()
```

to something like:

```
JFactory->getUser()
```

That is what I read by google the issue, but I cant figure out the correct code. Can some one advice?

Here is the compleate code section:

```
  $app    = JFactory::getApplication();
  $menu   = $app->getMenu();
  $active = $menu->getActive();
  $class  = $active->alias . " pageid-" . $active->id;
  $user =& JFactory::getUser();
  $userId = $user->get( 'id' );
  $username = $user->name;
```

Comment: I would say it is the `=&` that is your issue

Comment: I removed the & and the error messege is gone, thanks for advice ;)

Comment: If I recall correctly, `=&` was required in PHP/4 to assign objects by reference. That PHP version was obsoleted in 2004 so it isn't a syntax you need to care about any more. You'd have a serious issue though if your application codebase was actually 14 years old but, given that [Joomla/3.x requires PHP/5.3.10](https://downloads.joomla.org/technical-requirements), I presume it's not the case.

Answer (score 0):

**Quick solution:** Turn off error messages. Just go to "Global Configuration" in your backend, switch to the server tab and set the error reporting to none.
**Better solution:** if you upgraded your php version, thats because of it. if not, find that extension using this php code and upgrade it. next solution: if you use joomla 1.5 or 2.5 its better to upgrade to newer version.